# Totally differentiable in $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have been recently studying differentiability in regards to functions with multiple variables and I am not sure I if I understand the process completely.

Take for example, the function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whereas $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ an open set, with the function defined as

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}(x^2+y^2)\times \ln(x^2+y^2) & \text{ for } x^2+y^2 \neq0\\0 &\text{ otherwise.} \end {cases}$$

I can see that the function is a sum/product of differentiable functions, so the only problem that could arise is in $(0,0)$.
By definition total differentiability implies there exists $r:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $x\rightarrow f(x) -(f(a)+A\times (x-a))$ , which in our case is $(x,y)\rightarrow f(x,y) -(f(0,0)+A\times ((x,y)-(0,0))$ where $A$ is the Jacobi-Matrix, and having computed the partial derivatives, I came to the conclusion that $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}(0,0)=\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}(0,0)=0$ so $r$ is essentially $f$.

If i have everything is correct all I have to check is $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{(x^2+y^2)\ln(x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}?$$
And after rewriting $(x^2+y^2) = (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2$ and simplifying how do I proceed?

Comment: Try swapping to polar and check that the limit as $r$ goes to zero exists and is independent of $\theta$.